# Postgresql - encrypt jsonb data

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a jsonb column in my postgres table where I am storing json data. I want to store the data in an encrypted format and be able to query and get the plain text value. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`pgcrypto`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html) extenstion.

```
create extension if not exists pgcrypto;
```

If you want to alter an existing `jsonb` column to encrypted one, change the type of the column to `bytea` and use a pair of the extension's encryption / decryption functions, e.g.:

```
create table my_table(id serial primary key, data jsonb);
insert into my_table (data) values
('{"key": "value"}');

alter table my_table
    alter data type bytea 
    using pgp_sym_encrypt(data::text, 'secret_password');

select pgp_sym_decrypt(data, 'secret_password')
from my_table;

 pgp_sym_decrypt  
------------------
 {"key": "value"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks @klin. I'll try!!